# как создать БД по имеющейся модели Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, миграция

Имеется проект на Django 1.11 с использованием БД, модели и миграций. Использовался PostgreSQL. На другом рабочем месте клонировали проект, установили PostgreSQL, но для запуска проекта необходимо создать БД.

*Как создать БД (пустую)* при помощи модели и миграций?

**Дополнение**

1. В командной разработке не участвую, но будет полезно узнать "универсальный" способ решения данной ситуации.
2. С удаленными или нет миграциями (в папка migrations) и при использовании `>python manage.py makemigrations` в результате выводится сообщение:

   ... 
   File "...lib\site-packages\psycopg2__init__.py", line 130, in connect
   conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) 
   psycopg2.OperationalError

   The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
   ...
   File "...lib\site-packages\psycopg2__init__.py", line 130, in connect
   conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
   django.db.utils.OperationalError

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Если не учавствуете в командной разработке, то первым делом удаляете все миграции в приложениях(папка migrations)
2. Выполняете в консоли команду manage.py makemigrations (создаёте новые миграции)
3. Выполняете в консоли команду manage.py migrate (применяете их)

После этих действий, у вас будет пустая бд, со всеми таблицами проекта.

Comment: Удалять-то зачем?

Comment: @andreymal, а какой в них смысл, в данном случае? Может там 5000 изменений.

Comment: А может и всего пять. Не надо удалять миграции, предварительно не убедившись, что это не создаст проблем никому из участников проекта.

Comment: @andreymal, миграции нужны чтобы координировать изменения во время разработки, между разработчиками. А если база создаётся с нуля, то предыдущие миграции нафик никому не впали.

Comment: Вот вы сами и объяснили, почему миграции удалять нельзя :) С чего вы взяли, что база создаётся с нуля у всех разработчиков сразу и в коррдинации нет надобности? Ничего такого автор не говорил.

Comment: @andreymal, автор написал, что надо создать пустую базу. Ну может я неверные выводы сделал. Ну я не понимаю, разработчик, что не может написать в консоли `manage.py migrate`? У него не должны такие вещи вызывать трудностей.

Comment: @andreymal, поправил с учётом на замечание.

Comment: Квалификация разработчиков бывает самая разнообразная ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Кстати, я тут сейчас вдруг подумал, что может вопрос вообще в том, что нужно как-то сделать `CREATE DATABASE`)) Надо бы уточнений от автора

Comment: @andreymal и Мистер Фикс - спасибо за Вашу помощь. Дополнил свой вопрос. Я еще не знаю как создавать БД через миграции или модель, даже не знаю, возможно ли это))

Comment: @EmptyMan, саму базу данных надо создать в 'posgresql', и указать имя и данные входа в эту базу в `settings.py`. С помощью джанговского орм можно только таблицы создать в указанной бд.

Comment: @МистерФикс спасибо! Как я понял, нельзя создать бд кодом, даже если все необходимое прописано в `settings.py` и модели.

Answer (score 0):

Первый и не самый лучший вариант - это.

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata

Будут проблемы с переносом если версии postgresql отличаются.

Второй вариант поинтересней:

На сервере - источнике запускаем

```
pg_dump -U <USERNAME> -O -x -c -s <DATABASE_NAME> > <DATABASE_NAME>.sql
```

На новом сервере

```
psql -U <USERNAME> <DATABASE_NAME> < <DATABASE_NAME>.sql
```

Не забываем, что БД на первом сервере должен быть приведен в соответствие, если менялись модели. Иначе возникнут пробемы с мигрцией или запуском приложения.

В конце же

```
django-admin flush
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проверить его в скором времени у меня не получится.